# Joomla! inserts \n in my language string

Tags: language

When I create a language string with multiple HTML elements Joomla! automatically inserts `\n` between them.

This shows up as a literal `\n` in the string.

Does anyone know why and how to overcome this issue?

**I insert**

```
<h2>This is a heading</h2>
<p>This is some body text</p>
```

**I see**

```
<h2>This is a heading</h2>
\n
<p>This is some body text</p>
\n
```

If I add the `\n` then I see `\\n` in the output

Comment: Can you clarify whether it's `/n` or `\n`?

Comment: Good point, yes it's `\n` I have updated the question

Comment: A major suggestion, don't put HTML in language string if you can help it. Only place I do is my extension description. Other than that, all HTML derives from layouts

Comment: I see, ok good idea, I'll just create loads of PHPs and each paragraph as a language string.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is expected. Language strings must not contain line breaks. Having them would cause invalid INI files. This is not a valid language file:

```
COM_EXAMPLE_MY_STRING="<h2>This is a heading</h2>
<p>This is some body text</p>"
```

This is valid:

```
COM_EXAMPLE_MY_STRING="<h2>This is a heading</h2>\n<p>This is some body text</p>"
```

**Thanks to @lodder for this suggestion**

Instead of using HTML in the language string, try creating multiple language strings.  Then call each language string independently and use PHP to surround the string with the HTML element you want.

Comment: Ok fine, I can add `\n` without getting too upset.  How do I stop it showing in the output?  In the output I get `\\n`.  Double slash.